Recreating a section style
I have an old document with a section/chapter style I’d like to recreate. I believe it was done using titlesec (though I might be mistaken), but my LaTeX skills (or styling sensibilities) aren’t quite strong enough to reproduce it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Hey there! Well, yes: you have to employ the titlesec package. Your sections title format is hang: it means that you can input something like \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection\hsp|\hsp}{0pt}{\large\bfseries} (and similar for the chapter). For the rest, it depends on the typeface name and I dont’t think that precisely the one of your picture is withing the standard font families.

@FrancescoContini - The titlesec package is not required to achieve the desired formatting effects.

@Mico Yes, you’re right: it isn’t a strictly necessary package. I was a bit superficial, maybe because carried away by the question which specifically mentioned this package. And, in fact, your answer perfectly demonstrates that the package isn’t essential indeed. I have to admit I haven’t looked that part of “The LaTeX Companion” yet. After all, I think adopting the package and reading its documentation might be a simpler way for a beginner (like myself) to get started and this is the reason why my comment is so «convinced», when writing ‘Well, yes: you have to employ the titlesec package’.

@FrancescoContini - No harm done. Sometimes, it's helpful to remember that there's usually a surprisingly large number of ways to get most things done in TeX and LaTeX land. See egreg's answer for a vivid demonstration of this claim. :-)

Here's a solution that employs (a) the sectsty and xcolor packages and (b) a technique I picked up year and years ago from the book "The LaTeX companion". Observe that this approach lets you make cross-references (via the usual \label-\ref mechanism) to sections and subsections that are not affected by the visual decorations.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for \textcolor macro
\usepackage{sectsty} % for \allsectionsfont macro
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries\large\raggedright}

\makeatletter
% Modify the appearance of section and subsection "numbers"
% (Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
% Define the appearance of "decorated" section and subsection numbers:
\newcommand\section@cntformat{%
   \thesection\hspace{6pt}\textcolor{blue}{\textbar}\hspace{6pt}} 
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{%
   \thesubsection\hspace{6pt}\textcolor{red}{\textbar}\hspace{6pt}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Basic stuff} 
\label{sec:basic}

\subsection{Probability measures and various and sundry random variables} 
\label{sec:prob_meas}

\bigskip
Cross-references to section \ref{sec:basic} and subsection \ref{sec:prob_meas}.

\end{document}


Thanks, this is what I needed. I would like the vertical bar to be thicker but I think I can manage from here.

@AakashGhosh - For a thicker bar, I suggest you replace \textbar with \rule[-0.55ex]{0.8pt}{2.3ex}, where 0.8pt is the width of the "rule".

I can't help with the font.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{sectionrule}{blue!60}
\colorlet{subsectionrule}{red!60}

\titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\LARGE}
 {\ghoshnumber{section}}
 {0pt}
 {\ghoshtitle{section}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\normalfont\LARGE}
 {\ghoshnumber{subsection}}
 {0pt}
 {\ghoshtitle{subsection}}

\newlength{\ghoshwidth}
\newcommand{\ghoshtitle}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\ghoshwidth}{\ghoshnumber{#1}}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimeval{\textwidth-\ghoshwidth}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\ghoshnumber}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \hspace{-1em}%
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \quad
    \color{#1rule}\ghoshrule
    \quad
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ghoshrule}{%
  \vrule height 1.2\fontcharht\font`0 depth 0.2\fontcharht\font`0 width 2pt
}

\begin{document}

\section{Basic stuff}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\subsection{Probability measure and Random variable}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\subsection{Probability measure and Random variable and something else}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}


